# Nodejs send function to ejs

Tags: node.js, function, express, ejs, embedded-javascript

in app.js :

```
    app.locals.count = function(id, call) {
var myId =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
db.collection('comment').aggregate({$match: {postid: myId}}, {$group : {_id: '$postid', nb: {$sum: 1}}}, 
function(err, cb){
for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) { var la = cb[i]; return call(la.nb);  };
});
}
```

in index.ejs :

```
<% count(indexpost._id, function( result ){ %> <%= result %> <% }); %>
```

// return no result but :

```
<% count(indexpost._id, function( result ){ %> <%= console.log(result) %> <% }); %>
```

return a result in a terminal..

How should I proceed for display result in index.ejs? thanks

EDIT #1   ####################################

```
app.locals.count = function(id, call){
var myId =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
var caca = ccount(myId);
call(caca);
}

function ccount(myId){
db.collection('comment').aggregate({$match: {postid: myId}}, {$group : {_id: '$postid', nb: {$sum: 1}}}, 
function(err, cb){
for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) {
  var la = cb[i];
  var value = la.nb;
  return la.nb;
};
});
}
```

in index.ejs // return undefined

but :

```
app.locals.count = function(id, call){
var myId =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
var caca = 2;
call(caca);
}
```

in index.ejs // return 2

ccount function bad method return..

Answer (score 0):

just register this function on app.locals rest of you rout logic remains same. now you can call the function on ejs

in app.js :

```
function count(id, call) {
var myId =  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)
db.collection('comment').aggregate({$match: {postid: myId}}, {$group : {_id: '$postid', nb: {$sum: 1}}}, 
function(err, cb){
for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) { var la = cb[i]; return call(la.nb);  };
});
}

app.locals.count =count ;
```

in index.ejs

```
% count(indexpost._id, function( result ){ %> <%= result %> <% }); %>
```

If you are having properties like title,text etc i assume you can do something like this

```
  <% result.forEach(function(item) { %>
<ul>
    <li><%= item.title%></li>

    <li><%= item.text%></li>
</ul>
  <% }); %>
```

Comment: what does result display in console? have you tried forEach part?

Comment: no, result is a number : <% indexpost.forEach( function( indexpost ){ %> <% count(indexpost._id, function( result ){ %> <%= result %> <% }); %> <% }); %>

Comment: so in console it is 1,2,3,4,5 like that?

Comment: GET / 304 36.328 ms - -
2
1
7
8
0

Comment: result in terminal after get index /

Comment: your server file should not be replace by mine you need to modify it with previous

Comment: i have 5 post displayed in index with foreach, the firt post have 2 comment, the second 1 comment..ect..

Comment: i think a callback method is bad in my function

Comment: dont return
for (i = 0; i < cb.length; i++) { var la = cb[i];   };
call(la);